# Google Cloud Run, Django and "no such table" during build

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run) to upload my existing Django project running locally on sqlite to Google Cloud Run / Postgres.

I have the cloud_sql_proxy service running and can sign into Postgres.

I am at the point of running the command

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudmigrate.yaml \
--substitutions _INSTANCE_NAME=INSTANCE_NAME,_REGION=REGION
```

It runs for a while making good progress but then fails with:

```
Step #2 - "apply migrations": django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: registration_setting
Finished Step #2 - "apply migrations"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I do have a settings table in my registration app. But I don't understand where its missing from. Is this just the first table it's trying to create? Do I have to do something first to have it create the initial tables in Postgres? When I inspect Postgres I don't see any tables created in it.

I tried wiping out my migration and pycache folders and recreating them.

Comment: Hi @AdamG, Have you followed the tutorial step by step? Have you also followed this [step](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#run-locally) to run the Django migrations to set up your models and assets.

Comment: Yes, I have followed all the steps in order. Yes, I performed that step. How does Django know to perform it on the remote DB instead of the local one?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the code from [this section](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#database_connection) in my project.

```
# Use django-environ to parse the connection string
DATABASES = {"default": env.db()}

# If the flag as been set, configure to use proxy
if os.getenv("USE_CLOUD_SQL_AUTH_PROXY", None):
    DATABASES["default"]["HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
    DATABASES["default"]["PORT"] = 5432
```